# Hibernate: Insert List<String> into database after calling another method on it and converting it to String: save the whole list in a single cell

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have this class that I'm trying to insert into a PostgreSQL database using Hibernate:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User  {
  private String name;
  private String email;

  private List<String> pets = new ArrayList<>();  //pets get added later

  //getters, setters, adders
}
```

In another file:

```java
public class Utils  {
  public static String listToString(List<?> list, String separator)  {
        String result = "";

        for (Object e: list)  {
            result += e.toString() + separator;
        }

        return result == "" ? result : result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf(separator));
    }
}
```

I want the user to be mapped to a `name  email  pets` table where pets value `Utils.listToString(user.getPets())`. Is it possible to achieve with Hibernate?

**EDIT**:

I made these changes to code

```
private List<String> pets= new CustomArrayList();
```

```
public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList<String> implements List<String> {
   @Override
   public String toString()  {
       return Utils.listToString(this, "\n");
    }
}
```

If using `CustomArrayList` makes it easier to achive, how do I get Hibernate to call its `toString` when saving in db?

**EDIT**:

I want everything to be saved **in the same table called pets**, I want **all elements of the list** to be saved in a **single** cell, in the same row, in the same column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use @OneToMany annotation [One-to-Many](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many). Then proceed with the save call.

Comment: Would it save the pets to another table? I want all the data to be saved in a single table and the whole list of pets to be saved in the same row of the same column

Comment: yes, what you need is create a PETS table, map your USER table with your pets table using primary key foreign key relation.